# What does the -Recurse flag do in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, flags

To be clear, I know what recursion is. My question essentially boils down to, what is the difference between these three commands:

- `Remove-Item -Force -Recurse dir/to/remove`
- `Remove-Item -Force dir/to/remove`
- `Remove-Item -Recurse dir/to/remove`

As far as I can tell, they all appear to do the same thing.

Comment: Have you looked at the [`Remove-Item` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item) to see what those parameters do?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using both -Force and -Recurse to execute the same function, remove a directory and it’s children, there isn’t a big difference here. You are achieving the same thing with different switches.

-Force won’t help you read or get items beneath a given directory, though. -Recurse is meant for this, say in the case of using Get-Childitem. So it really depends what you are doing with each switch.

With Remove-Item -Force, you are saying that you know what you are doing, just delete it, thus bypassing any subsequent prompt about children. You could also use -Confirm.

-Force also helps deal with hidden or read-only items.

With Remove-Item -Recurse, you are saying to get the directory and it’s children up front, then remove them.

Try Get-Childitem -Recurse, and you will see it’s purpose.